# JWPlayer Flash Player doesn't load the related video

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

I was tired for searching and get solution for displaying related video from JWPlayer Flash version. But.. this is working for HTML5 version,

my 'related.xml' file :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7mbR.png

and my javascript file is :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uWzH.png

the result is :

i.stack.imgur.com/MUlRh.png

what should i to do?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running please?